# Sentry Source Maps (STACKTRACE) .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, sentry

unfortunately I can not find anything on the Internet. How can I view Sorce Map in .NET C #?

example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hdaw.png

Answer (score 0):

The [Sentry SDK for .NET](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet) sends the stacktrace already with the event when the `pdb` files are deployed with the app.

There are [many sample projects in the repository](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/tree/master/samples). There's no such process as 'upload sourcemaps' for .NET.

Specifically for ASP.NET MVC (not ASP.NET Core) you can find samples here:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet-samples/